# mapping square-of-deviation in Scheme

Tags: scheme, standard-deviation, map-function

Can someone please help me solve this!!!, I'm not sure how to approach this.

[image]

> Write a function, `var-map`, that maps a list X to the  square of its deviation.  Thus the list `X = (x1 x2 ... xn)` should be carried to the list
>   `((x1 − X ̄ )^2 ... (xn − X ̄ )^2)`.
>
> You should use the `map` function. (For example, your function, when evaluated on the list
>   `(1 2 3 4 5)`, should return `(4 1 0 1 4)`.)

I understand what it wants but am not sure where to start, I know how to do the `map` function but not sure what to do with the square of deviation.

Comment: I'd start with "the square of its deviation" of a single value.

Comment: (define(square-of-deviation l)
   (expt (- l (average)) 2)).        like this?

Comment: a) `average` isn't defined; b) since you know how to use `map`, once this function is finished, you should be all set.

Comment: (define(square-of-deviation l)
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (expt (- (car l) (average l)) 2)))
           
(square-of-deviation '(1 2))        
              
(define (var-map l)
  (if (null? l)
      0
      (cons (square-of-deviation (car l))
            (map square-of-deviation (cdr l)))))

      
(var-map '(6))

Comment: Oog... you're mixing an explicit traversal (if null...) with the use of 'map'. That's not a good idea. It sounds like your instructor is trying to motivate the use of functions-defined-inside-other-functions. Specifically, the function that you're mapping over the elements of the list has to "know about" the average.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to write  the final perfect code right away, just write down the formula:

```
(define (foo X) 
    (map (lambda (xi) 
              (squared 
                   (difference xi (average X)))) 
         X))
```

*Now* implement the missing functions and *refactor* (e.g. if something is calculated over and over again many times, it is better to calculate it only once, in advance, and reuse the calculated value). Keep the original, inefficient code too as an executable specification, commented out or renamed.

So it's about the attitude. Just do it – by *small*, manageable steps.